# output:\ntorch-1.1.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform- Pytorch /cloud functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, pytorch

I'm trying to deploy a function on Cloud functions and I'm having trouble getting pytorch to work. I need either version 1.1, 1.2 or 1.3 (any version that has `torch.hub` functionality)

Here is what I have been trying in the requirments.txt for my function:

```
numpy==1.17.2
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.1.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Which results in the error:

```
Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:\ntorch-1.1.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.\n\nerror: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": XXX}}
```

And of course trying the various other url for `1.2` and `1.3` and the same thing happens.

What can I do to fix this/ what am I doing wrong??

Appreciate the help.

**-if this affects anything, I'm using Python 3.7 for my function and have been using the linux packages.**

**__________________________________________________________________________**

**Edit:** I've tried this in my requirments.txt:

```
numpy==1.17.0
torch==1.3.0
torchvision===0.4.1
```

And I now get the error:

```
Build failed: {"cacheStats": [{"status": "MISS", "hash": "1f6ebb5b3667b3d677184dbf04b82666XXX", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "global"}, {"status": "MISS", "hash": "1f6ebb5b3667b3d677184dbf04b826660b67c784608d4e4XXXXX", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "project"}]}
```

I've never had this error with any other library on cloud functions. If anyone has other suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That `cp27` means it's for python2.7. It's actually not a good idea to install from url, use the package name istead(like numpy==1.17.2)

Try something like `pip3 install torch torchvision`, this will give the latest stable(1.3) version with cuda 10.

Look at the pytorch's home page -  https://pytorch.org/ - for reference

Comment: I get another error, I'm going to post in above with what I'm doing( I might be doing something wrong)

Comment: Oops, missed the first part of your answer which was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this problem in the future, this is (one of) the methods you can use:

```
numpy==1.17.0
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Note the main difference being the `cp37` as mentioned by `Natthaphon Hongcharoen` above.